# Chevy sonic 2013 exhaust pipe

Tags: chevrolet, sonic, exhaust-leak

Why is it leaking from the exhaust pipe?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

It looks as though the joint between the side and end of the silencer/muffler has failed.

In some products these joints are welded, others are crimped. Yours looks like it was crimped, and the joint has come apart. I don't know exactly why one should fail, but if it was recently replaced it might be a manufacturing defect.

After I had an exhaust replaced I could hear a leak. I took it back and the fitter said

> Sometimes it can take a while for the baffles to stand up.

Smelling BS I replied

> If we sing *God Save The King* do you think that will help?

and pointed to the soot marks similar to your photo. He replaced the faulty exhaust with another.

But in answer to the question, if it is an old exhaust, the simple answer is because it has failed. If you know a skilled fitter it might be possible to repair it, but most will just want to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

That's water leaking from a hole in the pipe.  Water is a byproduct of combustion and it's normal to see water dripping from a tailpipe.  Since water also promotes corrosion, holes can form in weak spots in the metal and leaks will appear from those holes.